# how to align my image in the center IOS horizontally

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

Here is my image :

```
Obj *obj = ... obj has imageHref which is NSString

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:obj.imageHref]]; 
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
```

Depending on image size I can't figure out how to center it, any ideas ?

This is all inside method :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {    
    Obj *obj = ... obj has imageHref which is NSString

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:obj.imageHref]]; 
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];

    NSLog(@"%f", rect.size.width);
     NSLog(@"%f", rect.size.height);
}
```

Where `rect.size.width` prints 320.000000 and `rect.size.height` prints 416.000000

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - (image.size.width/2),
                             (self.view.frame.size.height / 2) - (image.size.height / 2),
                             image.size.width, 
                             image.size.height)];
```

edit:

As you are already in a UIView:

```
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width/2) - (image.size.width/2), (self.frame.size.height / 2) - (image.size.height / 2), image.size.width, image.size.height)];
```

Comment: Hmm...  There's no guarantee that a division of a width or a height by 2 stays as an integer.  I would add 'floor.'

Answer (score 24):

This or something very like this should centre horizontally.

```
CGPoint centerImageView = imageView.center;
centerImageView.x = self.view.center.x;
ImageView.center = centerImageView;
```

Comment: property of a center not found for type UIImage

Comment: but it has on UIImageView. I've updated my answer to make that obvious.

Comment: it has some issue.  1st line says `centerImageView` is `CGPoint` but 2nd line say it equivalent to `float`. 3rd line says `ImageView` instead of `imageView`.

Comment: @Damo you should add `.x` right after `centerImageView` in second line.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı thanks - there was a discrepancy - I think that should be closer to the mark now

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add a macro like this before `@interface` in .h class file
`#define COUNTMID(X,Y) (float) (X-Y)/2`
and then use it in code as
`float center COUNTMID(ParentView.frame.width,ChildView.frame.width)`
to place your ChildView view at horizontal center of ParentView 
I've also made a method, making a ChildView frame to be placed in the center of ParentView:

```
-(CGRect) CenterFrameOfView:(UIView *) ParentView forView:(UIView *) ChildView
{
    CGRect result = CGRectMake(COUNTMID(ParentView.frame.size.width,ChildView.frame.size.width),COUNTMID(ParentView.frame.size.height,ChildView.frame.height),ChildView.frame.size.width,ChildView.frame.size.height);
    return result;
}
```

Or with setFrame

```
-(void) CenterFrameOfView:(UIView *) ParentView forView:(UIView *) ChildView 
{
    CGRect result = CGRectMake(COUNTMID(ParentView.frame.size.width,ChildView.frame.size.width),COUNTMID(ParentView.frame.size.height,ChildView.frame.height),ChildView.frame.size.width,ChildView.frame.size.height);
    [ChildView setFrame:result];
}
```

Hope it helps